# ORACLE - How to use LAG to display strings from all previous rows into current row

Tags: oracle, window-functions

I have data like below:

| group | seq | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | scan |
| A | 2 | visit |
| A | 3 | pay |
| B | 1 | drink |
| B | 2 | rest |

I expect to have 1 new column "hist" like below:

| group | seq | activity | hist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | scan | NULL |
| A | 2 | visit | scan |
| A | 3 | pay | scan, visit |
| B | 1 | drink | NULL |
| B | 2 | rest | drink |

I was trying to solve with LAG function, but LAG only returns one row from previous instead of multiple.
Truly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT LISTAGG(activity, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq)
        FROM   table_name l
        WHERE  t."GROUP" = l."GROUP"
        AND    l.seq < t.seq
       ) AS hist
FROM   table_name t
```

Or a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(PRIOR activity, ','), 3) AS hist
FROM   table_name t
START WITH seq = 1
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR seq + 1 = seq
AND    PRIOR "GROUP" = "GROUP"
```

Or a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ("GROUP", seq, activity, hist) AS (
  SELECT "GROUP", seq, activity, NULL
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  seq = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT t."GROUP", t.seq, t.activity, r.hist || ',' || r.activity
  FROM   rsqfc r
         INNER JOIN table_name t
         ON (r."GROUP" = t."GROUP" AND r.seq + 1 = t.seq)
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY "GROUP" SET order_rn
SELECT "GROUP", seq, activity, SUBSTR(hist, 2) AS hist
FROM   rsqfc
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ("GROUP", seq, activity) AS
SELECT 'A', 1, 'scan'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, 'visit' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, 'pay'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 'drink' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, 'rest'  FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> | GROUP | SEQ | ACTIVITY | HIST |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 | scan | *null* |
> | A | 2 | visit | scan |
> | A | 3 | pay | scan,visit |
> | B | 1 | drink | *null* |
> | B | 2 | rest | drink |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4b0bf022738a43e871b1a958dbcf1380)*

Answer (score 0):

To aggregate strings in Oracle we use `LISAGG` function.

In general, you need a [`windowing_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) to specify a sliding window for analytic function to calculate running total.

But unfortunately [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) doesn't support it.

To simulate this behaviour you may use [`model_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2161264) of the `select` statement. Below is an example with explanation.

> ```
> select
>   group_
>   , activity
>   , seq
>   , hist
> from t
> model
>   /*Where to restart calculation*/
>   partition by (group_)
>   /*Add consecutive numbers to reference "previous" row per group.
>     May use "seq" column if its values are consecutive*/
>   dimension by (
>     row_number() over(
>       partition by group_
>       order by seq asc
>     ) as rn
>   )
>   measures (
>     /*Other columnns to return*/
>     activity
>     , cast(null as varchar2(1000)) as hist
>     , seq
>   )
>   rules update (
>     /*Apply this rule sequentially*/
>     hist[any] order by rn asc =
>       /*Previous concatenated result*/
>       hist[cv()-1]
>       /*Plus comma for the third row and tne next rows*/
>       || presentv(activity[cv()-2], ',', '') /**/
>       /*lus previous row's value*/
>       || activity[cv()-1]
>   )
> ```

> ```
> GROUP_ | ACTIVITY | SEQ | HIST      
> :----- | :------- | --: | :---------
> A      | scan     |   1 | null      
> A      | visit    |   2 | scan      
> A      | pay      |   3 | scan,visit
> B      | drink    |   1 | null      
> B      | rest     |   2 | drink
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d008d73a32cf39daa0855614b5e27b35)*

Answer (score 0):

Few more variants (without subqueries):

```sql
SELECT--+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE
       t.*,
       regexp_substr(
         listagg(activity, ',')
            within group(order by SEQ)
            over(partition by "GROUP")
        ,'^([^,]+,){'||(row_number()over(partition by "GROUP" order by seq)-1)||'}'
        )
        AS hist1
      ,xmlcast(
         xmlquery(
           'string-join($X/A/B[position()<$Y]/text(),",")'
           passing
            xmlelement("A", xmlagg(xmlelement("B", activity)) over(partition by "GROUP")) as x
           ,row_number()over(partition by "GROUP" order by seq) as y
          returning content
          )
         as varchar2(1000)
         ) hist2
FROM   table_name t;
```

DBFIddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9b477a2089d3beac62579d2b7103377a

Full test case with output:

```
with table_name ("GROUP", seq, activity) AS (
SELECT 'A', 1, 'scan'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 2, 'visit' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 3, 'pay'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 1, 'drink' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, 'rest'  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT--+ NO_XML_QUERY_REWRITE
       t.*,
       regexp_substr(
         listagg(activity, ',')
            within group(order by SEQ)
            over(partition by "GROUP")
        ,'^([^,]+,){'||(row_number()over(partition by "GROUP" order by seq)-1)||'}'
        )
        AS hist1
      ,xmlcast(
         xmlquery(
           'string-join($X/A/B[position()<$Y]/text(),",")'
           passing
            xmlelement("A", xmlagg(xmlelement("B", activity)) over(partition by "GROUP")) as x
           ,row_number()over(partition by "GROUP" order by seq) as y
          returning content
          )
         as varchar2(1000)
         ) hist2
FROM   table_name t;

GROUP         SEQ ACTIV HIST1                          HIST2
------ ---------- ----- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
A               1 scan
A               2 visit scan,                          scan
A               3 pay   scan,visit,                    scan,visit
B               1 drink
B               2 rest  drink,                         drink
```